# Does the LastModifiedDate gets updates on SFDC Object record if the Formula behind formula field in the object is updated?

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

Does the LastModifiedDate gets updated on SFDC Object record if the Formula behind formula field in the object is updated?

Answer (score 0):

No. You're changing metadata. Think like adding new column to table in database - it's different type of operation, no data is modified, triggers don't run...
Formulas are like views - calculated at runtime, the moment you view the record on a page or in a report.
There are ways to see who changed what (setup audit trail, tooling API can tell you who & when modified field definition, in REST API there's a call that will tell whether anything changed since X) but that's separate from actual records stored in table.